# Standard error of normalmixEM fit?

Tags: r, standard-error, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I fitted a mixture denstiy of two gaussians two my data. I now want to calculated the standard errors of the estimates via the boot.se command of the mixtools package. My question is now, if the output is correct? It seems a bit odd to me, so is this correct what I am doing and can I rely on the values?

My data: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=09285782882980618119

My code:

```
normalmix<-normalmixEM(dat,k=2,lambda=c(0.99024,(1-0.99024)),fast=FALSE,maxit=10000,epsilon = 1e-16,maxrestarts=1000)
normalmix$loglik
    normalmix$lambda

 se<-boot.se(normalmix,B=1000)

  se$lambda.se
      se$mu.se
  se$sigma.se
```

final results:

$\hat{\lambda}$   = 0.990238663

$\hat{\mu_1}$  =-0.00115

$\hat{\mu_2}$ =0.040176949

$\hat{\sigma_1}$ =0.012220305

$\hat{\sigma_2}$ =0.003247102

My problem now is - and thats why I feel uncomfortable about relying on the values - that the output of boot.se(normalmix) varies quite strong. So without changing the code and rerun it (with the same normalmix, so normalmix is not rerun again) I get different estimates of the standard error. I increased the default value for B from 100 to 1000. In the manual there is nothing said about any other randomness. So where does it come from? What should I do now?

Comment: Any help would still be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is better to construct other sorts of bootstrap confidence intervals that consider the possible asymmetry of the bootstrap distribution (*sd* assume a symmetric bootstrap distribution (actually normal) which is reasonable for large samples). The natural solution is: DIY. The following R code implements the bootstrap:

```
B = 1000 # Number of bootstrap samples
n = length(dat)
mu1b <- mu2b <- sigma1b <- sigma2b <- lambdab <- vector()

# Bootstrap
for(i in 1:B){
  print(i)
  dat1 = sample(dat,rep=T)
  normalmix <- normalmixEM(dat1, k=2, lambda=c(0.99024,(1-0.99024)), fast=FALSE, 
                           maxit=10000, epsilon = 1e-16, maxrestarts=1000)
  mu1b[i]    = normalmix$mu[1]      # $
  mu2b[i]    = normalmix$mu[2]      # $
  sigma1b[i] = normalmix$sigma[1]   # $
  sigma2b[i] = normalmix$sigma[2]   # $
  lambdab[i] = normalmix$lambda[1]  # $
}
```

Using the bootstrap samples you can construct bootstrap confidence intervals. The simplest are quantile-type which can be calculated as follows:

```
c(quantile(mu1b, 0.025), quantile(mu1b, 0.975))
```

For other types of bootstrap intervals see: [DiCiccio & Efron (1996).  Bootstrap confidence intervals](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-11/issue-3/Bootstrap-confidence-intervals/10.1214/ss/1032280214.full)

Comment: thanks, but what is DIY? And what do you mean by "sd assume a symmetric..." what is sd? you mean boot.se? And the code you created (thanks for this!) does not give the standard errors or? I mean, you do the bootstrap, but what are the standard errors? I am not good at this, thats why I have to ask...This is a bit above my knowledge level......

Comment: mh, ok, I also do not know how to implement the information-based method and yes, I read the great book of McLachlan, but this is not helping me how to implement these things. I will leave it out of my thesis and give the estimates without standard errors.